# App Script Editor - "Cannot find method formatDate(object,string,string)"

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a script in Apps Script that will count a habit streak.  It will use today's date to find the correct column on the Sheet and count backwards from there until it hits a missed day.  To get today's date, I'm trying to use:

`Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "yyyy.MM.dd");`,

which keeps giving me the error:

"Cannot find method formatDate(object,string,string)"

My code uses exactly the same syntax as they show on the [references](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format) page other than my changing the time zone from "GMT" to "EST", but changing it back to "GMT" or to "GMT-5" didn't fix it, so I'm kind of at a loss.

I think it's an issue creating the date object from "new Date()", as I've tried to use other date methods like `Date.now()` to which it throws up "TypeError: Cannot find function now in object [object Object]."  I figured this may be something to do with my scopes but I checked and it looked like I had all the ones I needed.

I also tried creating the Date object separately and then passing the variable into formatDate but had the same result.

Code I've tried is:

```
var day = Utilities.formatDate(day, "GMT-5", "yyyy.MM.dd");

------
var day = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "yyyy.MM.dd");
------
var day = new Date();
var day = day.now();
```

Let me know if you need more to go off of than that.  Any help is appreciated, even if it's just using a different method to set a variable equal to today's date, thanks!!!

Comment: Try isolating the issue> create a new project>add in only one function> one line with utilities. See [mcve]

Comment: WOW!
That worked immediately.  Copied my code to the new project and it no longer gives the error.  Any idea what the difference may be between them? 
Either way thanks so much!

Comment: You probably have conflicting variables somewhere, like  variables with the same name. `day` is a common name... you might've used it in any of the other file scripts attached.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue.

I have run the following test:
```lang-js
function test() {
  Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "yyyy.MM.dd"));
  // output: "2020.02.07"
}
```

Comment: @Aerials, the bug must have resulted from something like TheMaster suggested where I likely had the same variable name in different scripts. Moving the code to an empty project resolved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as I created a new project the utilities starting working properly.
From @TheMaster's comments:

Try isolating the issue> create a new project>add in only one function> one line with utilities. See minimal reproducible example

You probably have conflicting variables somewhere, like variables with the same name. day is a common name... you might've used it in any of the other file scripts attached.

Answer (score 0):

I got same situation, but i can fix it.

You did `Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "yyyy.MM.dd");`

You may change like the following

`var date = new Date;
 var today= new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
 today = Utilities.formatDate(today, "EST", "yyyy/MM/dd");`

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following test in your script:

```js
function test() {
  Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "yyyy.MM.dd"));
  // output: "2020.02.07"
}
```

I got the expected output. As @TheMaster points out, you probably have conflicting variable names somewhere.

Comment: Yeah his initial comment ended up fixing the problem.  This was my first Apps Script project (I'm very new to coding as it is) and I didn't realize that you couldn't use the same variable names in different scripts within the same project.  What's confusing is I did try to use new variables that I had assigned "new Date()" to and it still didn't work, but clearly I did something wrong as once I moved the code to a new project with no other scripts it worked fine.


Anyway, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept any answer you prefer, as comments are not answers, and the question will remain with no answer accepted. Maybe @TheMaster can answer.  [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)
[What if I answer a question in a comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294791/what-if-i-answer-a-question-in-a-comment)

Comment: Created a new answer that'll point people towards his comment as an answer.  Thanks again!